# jsoup convert my url to sth else and get 404 error

Tags: java, encoding, jsoup

i get this exception when i use URL with Persian character in jsoup
i copied the url from Browser's addressBar
code :

```
String url = "http://www.tahlildadeh.com/%D8%A2%D9%85%D9%88%D8%B2%D8%B4/%D8%A2%D9%85%D9%88%D8%B2%D8%B4-%DA%AF%D8%A7%D9%85-%D8%A8%D9%87-%DA%AF%D8%A7%D9%85-%D8%A7%D9%86%D8%AF%D8%B1%D9%88%DB%8C%D8%AF";
    Document document = Jsoup.connect(url).data("query", "Java")
            .userAgent("...")
            .timeout(10000)
            .post();
    System.out.println(document.title());
```

exception:

```
Exception in thread "main" org.jsoup.HttpStatusException: HTTP error fetching URL. Status=404, URL=http://www.tahlildadeh.com/%25d8%25a2%25d9%2585%25d9%2588%25d8%25b2%25d8%25b4/%25d8%25a2%25d9%2585%25d9%2588%25d8%25b2%25d8%25b4-%25da%25af%25d8%25a7%25d9%2585-%25d8%25a8%25d9%2587-%25da%25af%25d8%25a7%25d9%2585-%25d8%25a7%25d9%2586%25d8%25af%25d8%25b1%25d9%2588%25db%258c%25d8%25af
```

the problem is that actual url and url in exception are different and i get 404 error when i open that link with browser.

Answer (score 0):

I am using Jsoup Version 1.8.3 and It seems to be working fine.
[image]